# How to use onload function in rails view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm want to load a function when the form is completely loaded. 
This is my controller with the function which receive the ajax:

```
def get_component_from_work
  @work = Work.find(params[:work_id])
  @components=@work.components
  @work = Work.find(params[:work_id])
  @start = @work.start_date_of_work
  @finish = @work.real_end_date_of_work
  @entity = @work.entity.name
    contr = Entity.find(@work.contractor_id)
  @contractor = contr.name
  render json: {:start=>@start, :finish=>@finish, :entity=>@entity, :contractor=>@contractor, :component_work => @components}  
end
```

This is my form:

```
.panel.panel-default
  .panel-heading
    %h4.panel-title
      %a{"data-parent" => "#accordion-ce", "data-toggle" => "collapse", href: "#collapse"+@reg.to_s+"-1"}
        %i.fa.fa-fw.fa-plus-circle.txt-color-green
        %i.fa.fa-fw.fa-minus-circle.txt-color-red
        Certificados
  .panel-collapse.collapse.in{ 'id'=> "collapse"+@reg.to_s+"-1"}
    .panel-body
      .row
        .col-sm-4
          %label Nombre de la obra
          %select.form-control{'class'=>'work-select', name: "professional[certificates_attributes][" + @reg.to_s + "][work_id]", onchange: 'workSelectCH(this);', onkeyup:'workSelectKU(this);'}
            %option
            -@work.each do |wc|
              %option{value: "#{wc.id}"} 
                = "#{wc.name}"
          %input{'class'=>'change-check' ,type: "checkbox", :value=> "otros", onchange:'check(this);'}
            = "No es una de las Obras?"
        .col-sm-4{'class' =>'another_work' ,style: "display:none;"}
          %label Nombre de Otra Obra
          %input.form-control{name: "professional[certificates_attributes][" + @reg.to_s + "][other_work_attributes][name]"}
        .col-sm-2
          %label Inicio de la obra: 
          %label.input{'class'=>'start_other_works', 'style'=>'display:none;'}
            %input.form-control{name:"professional[certificates_attributes][" + @reg.to_s + "][other_work_attributes][start]",  as: :date, type:  "date"}
          %label.input{'class'=>'start_certificate'}
            %input.form-control{:disabled=>"disabled", as: :date, type:  "date"}
        .col-sm-2
          %label Termino de la obra: 
          %label.input{'class'=>'finish_other_works', 'style'=>'display:none;'}
            %input.form-control{name: "professional[certificates_attributes][" + @reg.to_s + "][other_work_attributes][end]", as: :date, type:  "date"}
          %label.input{'class'=>'finish_certificate'}
            %input.form-control{:disabled=>"disabled", as: :date, type:  "date"}
        .col-sm-4{'class'=>'specialty-select', style: "display:none;"}
          %label Especialidad
          %br
          .input-group
            %select.form-control{:name =>"professional[certificates_attributes][" +@reg.to_s + "][other_work_attributes][specialty]"}
              %option
              %option{:value => "Saneamiento"} Saneamiento
              %option{:value => "Civil"} Civil
              %option{:value => "Electromecanico"} Electromecanico
              %option{:value => "Hidraulica"} Hidráulica
            %span.input-group-addon
              %i.fa.fa-money
      %br
      .row{'class'=>'2'}
        .col-sm-4
          %label Entidad contratante
          .input-group{'class'=>'entity_other_works', 'style'=>'display:none;'}
            %input.form-control{name: "professional[certificates_attributes][" + @reg.to_s + "][other_work_attributes][entity]"}
            %span.input-group-addon
              %i.fa.fa-gears
          .input-group{'class'=>'entity'}
            %input.form-control{:disabled=>"disabled"}
            %span.input-group-addon
              %i.fa.fa-gears
        .col-sm-4
          %label Contratista
          .input-group{'class'=>'contractor_other_works', 'style'=>'display:none;'}
            %input.form-control{ name: "professional[certificates_attributes][" + @reg.to_s + "][other_work_attributes][contractor]"}
            %span.input-group-addon
              %i.fa.fa-gears
          .input-group{'class'=>'contractor'}
            %input.form-control{:disabled=>"disabled"}
            %span.input-group-addon
              %i.fa.fa-gears

        .col-sm-4
          %label Cargo
          %select.form-control#charge{name: "professional[certificates_attributes][" + @reg.to_s + "][charge_id]"}
            -@charge.each do |wc|
              %option{value: "#{wc.id}"} 
                = "#{wc.name}"
      %br
      .row{'class'=>'3'} 
        .col-sm-4
          %label Cantidad de días trabajados
          %input.form-control{'class'=>'worked-day', name: "professional[certificates_attributes][" + @reg.to_s + "][num_days]", :disabled=>"disabled"}

      %br
      .row
        .col-sm-2
          //%a.btn.btn-primary{href: 'javascript:void(0);', :onclick => 'add_dates(this);'} Agregar más fechas

      %br
      .row{'class'=>'fechas'}
        .col-sm-4
          %label.col-sm-4 Fecha de Inicio:
          .col-sm-8
            .input-group
              %input.form-control{'class'=>'start-worker', name: "professional[certificates_attributes][" + @reg.to_s + "][start_date]", as: :date, type:  "date"}
              %span.input-group-addon
                %i.fa.fa-calendar

        .col-sm-4
          %label.col-sm-4.control-label Fecha de Termino:
          .col-sm-8
            .input-group
              %input.form-control{'class'=>'finish-worker', name:"professional[certificates_attributes][" + @reg.to_s + "][finish_date]", as: :date, type:  "date", onchange:'calculateDays(this);'}
              %span.input-group-addon
                %i.fa.fa-calendar
      %br
      .row
        .col-sm-12
          .new-date 
      .row{'class'=>'comp2'}
        .col-sm-6
          %label Componentes de la obra:
          %br
          .col-sm-4
            %label#get-comp
              %label.select.components{'class'=>'comp-check'}
      .row{'class'=>'comp'}
        .col-sm-6
          .col-sm-4{'class'=>'comp', style: "display:none;"}
            -if @component !=nil
              - @component.each do |comp|
                %input{name: "professional[certificates_attributes][" + @reg.to_s + "][other_work_attributes][component_work]", type: "checkbox", :value=> "#{comp.id}"}
                  = "#{comp.name}"
                %br
      %fieldset
        %legend Archivos a Adjuntar
        .row
          .col-sm-6
            %label.col-sm-2 Certificado
            .col-sm-10
              .button
                = file_field_tag "professional[certificates_attributes][" + @reg.to_s + "][certificate]", class: 'btn btn-default', label: false, onchange: "this.parentNode.nextSibling.value = this.value", as: "file"
          .col-sm-6
            %label.col-sm-2 Otro
            .col-sm-10
              .button
                = file_field_tag "professional[certificates_attributes][" + @reg.to_s + "][other]", class: 'btn btn-default', label: false, onchange: "this.parentNode.nextSibling.value = this.value", as: "file"
```

When the page is completely load, some fields have to be completed with this js code using ajax:

```
function complete_infocombo(element, url, work_id, form_token, default_value){
var str_html = "";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    async: false,
    data: { work_id: work_id, authenticity_token: form_token}
}).done(function( data ) {
  var start = data.start;
  var finish = data.finish;
  var entity = data.entity;
  var contractor = data.contractor;
  newOptions = [];
  $.each(data.component_work, function(key, value){
    item = {};
    item['name'] = value.name;
    item['id'] = value.id;
    newOptions.push(item);
  });
  $(element).parent().parent().parent().children('.comp2.row').children('.col-sm-6').children('.col-sm-4').children('#get-comp').children('.comp-check.components.select').empty();
  $.each(newOptions, function(key,value){
    str_html = str_html + "<label> <strong> > </strong> " + value.name + "</label><br/>"
  });
  $(element).parent().parent().parent().children('.comp2.row').children('.col-sm-6').children('.col-sm-4').children('#get-comp').children('.comp-check.components.select').html(str_html);
  $(element).parent().parent().children().children('.start_certificate').find('input').empty();
  $(element).parent().parent().children().children('.start_certificate').find('input').val(start);
  $(element).parent().parent().children().children('.finish_certificate').find('input').empty();
  $(element).parent().parent().children().children('.finish_certificate').find('input').val(finish);
  $(element).parent().parent().parent().children('.2.row').children('.col-sm-4').children('.entity.input-group').find('input').empty();
  $(element).parent().parent().parent().children('.2.row').children('.col-sm-4').children('.entity.input-group').find('input').val(entity);
  $(element).parent().parent().parent().children('.2.row').children('.col-sm-4').children('.contractor.input-group').find('input').empty();
  $(element).parent().parent().parent().children('.2.row').children('.col-sm-4').children('.contractor.input-group').find('input').val(contractor);
    });
  }
```

I use the $(element) because I have a button which create a new certificate in the same form, after all is complete load I have to select one of the fields so the js works, but I want to the function work when the page is loaded and show the information in the field. I know that  html triggered the function onload and it works, is any way to do the same in rails?

Comment: why do you have `@work = Work.find(params[:work_id])` twice in your controller?

Comment: it's a mistake, I didn't realize that. thanks

Comment: And also your jQuery could use $(element).parents().eq(n); where `n` is the nth parent to avoid too much repetition.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to the function work when the page is loaded and show the
>   information in the field

You'll be best looking at how [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) works, as this will be the main cause of issues here

If you want to trigger events after the `DOM` has loaded, I would recommend using the [Turbolinks event handlers](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events) to manage the code:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
var ready = function(){
    // your code
};
$(document).on("page:load ready", ready);
```

Answer (score 0):

This was helpful to me as well, but I had to make the following change to get it to work.

```
$(document).on("page:load ready", ready());
```

Unfortunately, I do not have enough rep points to comment.

Comment: What was helpful to you? If you're providing a unique and useful answer, it should stand alone. And if you're commenting on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23635986/1255289) you're wrong. The second argument to an event handler should be a callable function object, not the return from that function.

Comment: Like I mentioned, I used an answer instead of a comment because I do not have enough rep points to comment on an answer, but apparently can comment on a comment.  Yes, the answer you linked to was the answer I was commenting on.
When I use the code exactly as written in the original answer, nothing happens, but when I use the code where I added the parens, the 'ready' function is executed.  If you would be so kind as to move my answer into a comment where it belongs, I would appreciate it.